# How to create a column in pd.DataFrame that has multiple columns from another FataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as the shown below:

```
column_0 column_1 column_2 column_3
   11      1       2        3
   12      4       5        6
   13      7       8        9
```

and I want to have a final dataframe to import to BigQuery as follows:

```
column_0  column_1   final_column

                   column_2 column_3

  11        1         2        3
  12        4         5        6
  13        7         8        9
```

I've been trying to find a solution but only get documentation to merge, sum, pivot, stack, melt... but i dont want to mix values, just make something as a struct in SQL without using SQL (in BigQuery)

May anyone help me get this done? Thanks!

Edit: i added another column at the beginning to show the problem in a more realistic way

Answer (score 0):

You can [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the columns(s) to leave as top level, then prepend a level with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), finally [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to set your initial saved column(s) as top level:

```
df2 = pd.concat({'final_column': df.set_index('column_1')}, axis=1).reset_index()
```

output:

```
  column_1 final_column         
               column_2 column_3
0        1            2        3
1        4            5        6
2        7            8        9
```

intermediates:

```
# set_index

          column_2  column_3
column_1                    
1                2         3
4                5         6
7                8         9

# prepend a level with concat

         final_column         
             column_2 column_3
column_1                      
1                   2        3
4                   5        6
7                   8        9
```